# Malware installation during plugin update?

Tags: plugins, security, updates

I update my wordpress blog daily (current version: WordPress 3.5.2). Today I installed an update of "Search everything". After that, my webspace was infected by malware.

Interestingly, my blog is hidden using .htaccess, and I'm the only one using it. My provider emailed me, that the infection took place via wordpress.

How can I find out I the plug-in contains the malware? Is there a list with the latest security issues?

Comment: First: Please link to the plugin. Second: Tell us the version. Third: Never trust your hoster when they tell you where an infection is coming from :)

Comment: It's unlikely this was caused by a plugin update and that specific plugin, though possible. It could be your theme or another plugin or even your home computer, or of course the host.